# how to take a snapshot then append results to another table SQL

Tags: sql

at the end of the month I need to take a snapshot and then append the results into a table that accumulates each snapshots data.  How can I achieve this please.

I.e. do I schedule a store procedure to run every month that updates a temp table and then another procedure updates the table?  or is there a better way?

Regards,
Laura

Comment: What do you mean by "snapshot" - do you mean a dump of the table contents?

Comment: If you're constantly appending a table's entire contents with its contents from previous copies then you'll encounter exponential-like growth, this would be a bad thing. Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: ...and why not just take backups using your DBMS' built-in backup functionality?

Comment: Hi Dai,  by snapshot I mean to run a query and the results from that query is what gets appended to a separate table.